# How to remove a common prefix pattern from multiple file names in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, rename, wildcard-expansion

I would need to rename thousands of files, right now I'm doing it with removing first x characters, but it can be a lengthy process since the number of chars needed to be removed changes.

Source files are named like this:

```
4023 - 23 - Animal, crocodile 4 legs.txt 
243 - 4 - Animal, dog 4 legs.txt 
5450 - 2 - Animal, bird 2 legs.txt
```

Renamed:

```
Animal, crocodile 4 legs.txt
Animal, dog 4 legs.txt
Animal, bird 2 legs.txt
```

It seems the easiest it would be to trim everything before "A" appears, but I do not know how to do this. Something with a loop that could be used as a bash script would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bash parameter expansion](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

`${VAR#*-*- }`

to remove a prefix by pattern. That's using the text in the shell variable VAR and generating a string based on removing a prefix that matches the wildcard pattern `*-*-` - e.g. any characters then a dash then any characters and then a second dash and a space

In order to get the filenames in a loop you can just use a bash `for` with a pattern

```
for VAR in *.txt; do mv "$VAR" "${VAR#*-*- }"; done
```

the quoting is necessary in the `mv` to prevent the whitespace in the filenames being split up into multiple arguments by the shell

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cut -d"-" -f3`:

```
for VAR in *-*-*.txt; do mv "$VAR" "`echo $VAR | cut -d'-' -f3 `"; done
```

or, to ignore the first space:

```
for VAR in *-*-*.txt; do mv "$VAR" "`echo $VAR | sed -e 's/^.*- //g'`"; done
```